# How can I select from different tables in one MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, relation

```
table1
id firstname
-------------
1 Elon
2 Steve


table2
id profession
-------------
1 Entrepreneur
2 Engineer


table3
firstname profession
-------------
1 2
2 1
```

Need result:

```
firstname profession
-------------
Elon Engineer
Steve Entrepreneur
```

How can I select from different tables in one MySQL query?
How can I select from different tables in one MySQL query?

Comment: before asking here please learn some sql queries if you post your question in google search means you get lots of help https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=cHoBVLKOAYfW8gfqqYDoCw&gws_rd=ssl#q=How+can+I+select+from+different+tables+in+one+MySQL+query%3F

Comment: Use a JOIN on relevant columns?

Comment: use jois: left, right or inner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement should give you the result you needed.

```
select t1.firstname, t2.profession from table1 t1 join table3 t3 on t1.id=t3.firstname join table2 t2 on t3.profession = t2.profession
```

Comment: #1146 - Table 'test.t2' doesn't exist

Comment: @user2429282 had a misstake in the query, can you try it again?

Comment: @user2429282 can you show the create statements of your tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
SELECT t1.firstname, t2.profession
   FROM table1 as t1
   LEFT JOIN table3 as t3 ON t1.id = t3.firstname
   LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 on t2.id = t3.profession
```

this one works, tested

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 't2.profession' in 'field list'

Comment: than you dont have column with that name, why dont you give us:
describe table1;
describe table2;
describe table3;

Comment: i edited my post, this query is tested and its working